# Xamarin.iOS ,how to share view controllers between two projects with different stoaryboards

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin . I am working on  a Xamrin.iOS app that uses one theme and resources, now i want a different version of the app  with a different theme and resource files but with same functionalities.

I have tried creating a new storyboard by specifying it in info.plist file but the application won't install even on the simulator.I am on Xamarin  Visual Studio.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was because my Navigation controller becomes null somehow and app crashed due null reference.

After making a navigation controller as the Titleview controller i was able to use the new storyboard [as in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFvUB.png) .